# RunTime Error when trying to take String input using readLine in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, readline

I am a beginner in kotlin and this is the code I tried to execute, but **runtime error** is being displayed. Please help me resolve this.

```
import java.util.*
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    var inp = Scanner(System.`in`);
    var t:Int = inp.nextInt();
    repeat(t)
    {
        var n:Int = inp.nextInt();
        var s:String = readLine()!!
        for (i in s)
        {
            println(i);
        }
        println()
        
    }
}
```

**Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
at ProgKt.main(prog.kt:10)** This is the error that is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Smeki's answer is right, but I just need to point something out since you're a beginner and it might get confusing.

Normally you'd do something like this:

`val s = readLine()`

Notice you're not specifying the *type* of `s` - it's being inferred by whatever you're assigning to it. Because `readLine` returns a nullable `String?`, which is a `String` that *could be null* (which is what the `?` on the end means), then the compiler knows that `s` is a `String?`. It's the equivalent of doing this:

```
val s: String? = readLine()
```

And you can do that explicitly if you want! You usually don't need to though. And now you have your nullable `s`, you can do some null-checking to use it safely:

```
if (s != null) {
    // we know it's not null, so now you can do stuff with it
} else {
    // if you like, you can handle the null case separately, like breaking out of 
    // the loop (since null from readLine() means you've reached the end)
}
```

There's other ways to handle nulls and do null-checking - [here's the documentation about it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) and I'd **strongly** recommend reading it and getting your head around it - it's a key part of the language! And it makes your life easier and code safer in the long run (avoids problems like this! `!!` gets around null-safety and it's usually a bad sign)

---

But remember when I said you can explicitly declare the type for `s`? Here's what I said it would be, and what you've written:

```
// correct
val s: String? = readLine()
// something's different!
val s: String = readLine()
```

See how you're missing the `?` that says its a *nullable* type? Even if you're planning to null-check `s` after this, **it's going to crash at this line** because `s` is declared as a non-null type, and `readLine()` is gonna to be *null* at some point. When you assign *null* to a *non-null* variable, it'll crash with an error - because as far as the compiler's concerned, something's gone wrong.

(You should also get some warnings in your IDE if you're using one, trying to null-check a variable that you've declared as *non-null* will give you some "why are you trying to do this? It can't be null, right?" messages that hint that something's wrong somewhere. Also if you didn't add the `!!` after `readLine()`, you'd get a warning about that - probably why you added the `!!` in the first place! It doesn't make the problem go away, just stops the IDE from warning you about it)

---

Also you might have noticed, I made `s` a `val` instead of a `var` because it's a fixed value you're not going to change - always prefer `val`s unless you definitely need to change that variable, it's not such a big deal here but it makes some other things easier (you'll get warnings about that too)

Comment: Since this answer already goes quite in depth in explaining null safety, for completeness, I'd recommend to OP to also read [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html). Especially the part about the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) which might be usable in this scenario as well.

Comment: @cactustictacs Thank You for your well detailed explanation. *Now I get it. I explicitly used **var** since, **val** is unmutable and can be quite difficult to use when trying to code for competitive programming and I might need to reassign a new string to the variable* ;D

Comment: @AvinashDoddi you're not reassigning it though! You just create a new one every loop and it's initialised with the result of `readLine` and it never changes over its lifetime - it should be a `val`, that's the right tool for the job. `var`s are useful too, but if you use them for a value that doesn't change, your intent is less clear. And it can cause issues with smart casting and null-checking, because if you check a `var` isn't null, that value could be changed to null while you're using it (depending on the `var`'s visibility). So the compiler can't make guarantees like it can with a `val`

Answer (score 1):

Well, NPE is the most probably thrown from

```
var s:String = readLine()!!
```

where those !! are part of [kotlin null-safety feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator).
And from java doc of readLine() we can find out when is null returned.

```
/**
 * Reads a line of input from the standard input stream.
 *
 * @return the line read or `null` if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.
 */
fun readLine(): String? = LineReader.readLine(System.`in`, Charset.defaultCharset())
```